# Nginx alias with laravel4

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-4

My nginx configuration for laravel

```
 server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     app.dev;
        rewrite_log     on;
        root            /var/www/l4/angular;
        index         index.html;

        location /{
        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
            try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }
        location /lara/ {
          index index.php;
          alias /var/www/l4/public/;
        }
        # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
        if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }
        location ~ ^/lara/(.*\.php)$ {
              alias /var/www/l4/public/$1;
                      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                      fastcgi_index index.php;
                      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                      include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Laravel route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::get('x', function()
{
    return "alpha";
});
```

my problem is,"http://app.dev/lara/index.php" is working but "http://app.dev/lara" and lara/x is not working.

Comment: ...have you tried to point it to `app/index.php` inside laravel's folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, make the following edits. An explanation of why is below.

Replace

```
try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

with

```
try_files   $uri $uri/ /lara/index.php?$query_string;
```

Replace the last location directive with this

```
location ~ /lara/(.*)$ {
                  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                  fastcgi_index index.php;

                  include fastcgi_params;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "/var/www/l4/public/index.php";
                  fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /$1;
}
```

Restart nginx.

Now the why. I spotted a couple of mistakes with your nginx config. First, `/index.php?$query_string` in the `try_files` directive should be `/lara/index.php?$query_string`, otherwise nginx will try a request like `http://app.dev/lara` as `/var/www/l4/angular/index.php?`, which leads no where (unless you have an index.php there, and even is it will be served as text, not through fpm).

The second has to do with the `location ~ ^/lara/(.*\.php)$` directive. I think restricting it to URIs that end with .php is wrong, because it won't work for `http://app.dev/lara/x`, which will make nginx only search for `/var/www/l4/public/x`, returning 404 of course. Changing the regex to `^/lara/(.*)$` should do the job of catching `/lara/x`. Now the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` directive is erroneous because for `http://app.dev/lara/x`, `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is `/var/www/l4/public/x/lara/x`, and removing the `$1` in the alias directive won't make it any better. Instead, make the `fastcgi_param` like this `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  "/var/www/l4/public/index.php";`, remove the alias directive, it's useless now, then move `include fastcgi_params;` above the `fastcgi_param` so it won't override `SCRIPT_FILENAME` value.

Done? Not yet :). Trying `/lara/x` will show a Laravel routing error, because it tries to find the route `lara/x` instead of `x`, this is because you're including `fastcgi_params`. Just add `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /$1;` after `SCRIPT_FILENAME` param directive. Now it should be working fine. Don't forget to restart nginx :).